# How can I change the .htaccess file in WordPress so that it will allow cross browser domain access?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I edited my WordPress .htaccess to allow cross browser domain access but it isn't working. The updated code is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /articles/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /articles/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Not sure why it isn't working. The JQuery code that I am using to parse the XML feed is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    function parse(document){
        $(document).find("item").each(function(){
            $("#content").append(
                '<br /> Title: '+$(this).find('title').text()+
                '<br /> Author: '+$(this).find('link').text()+
                '</p>'
            );
        });
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.knead-nyc.com/articles/feed/', // name of file you want to parse
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parse,
        error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: FYI: Doing this would be a horrible security risk, in the case allowing any website to hijack your session and do anything it wants in the admin panel as you were doing it.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But is there a way to only allow feeds from "http://www.knead-nyc.com/"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Although I was on the same domain (example.com) I was getting the following error. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.org/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://www.example.org is therefore not allowed access"

I found out occasionally, the same origin policy may block requests between sub-domains on the same domain. So after a few searches I was able to solve this problem by by adding document.domain within my JavaScript. For example:
    document.domain = 'example.com';
I also removed:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

from the .htaccess file since it wasn't needed any more and as  Alexander O'Mara pointed out causes a security risk.